# I am trying to update my twitter status and read my timeline using twitter4j

Tags: java

```
import twitter4j.*;

import java.util.*;

import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //new login();

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXX")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXX")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXXX");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        twitter4j.Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        I am trying to update status on my twitter
        try {
            Status status = twitter.updateStatus("Anything");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Status> status = null;
        try {
            status = twitter.getHomeTimeline();

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(Status st : status) 
        {
            System.out.println(st.getUser().getName());
            System.out.println(st.getText());
        }


    }

}
```

Please help me, I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at twitter4j.TwitterFactory.<clinit>(TwitterFactory.java:86)
```

Comment: Try to rename your class to something valid, like MyTwitterClient.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download and import OKhttp (http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and okio (https://github.com/square/okio) jar files into your project. Should fix the problem.